# Bertsekas' Penalty Approach's Proof of Necessary Conditions of the Equality Constrant Problem using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: limits, optimization, proof-explanation, lagrange-multiplier

I am having some trouble understanding the proof of the Necessary Conditions of the ECP using Lagrange Multipliers in Bertsekas' book *Nonlinear programming* (1999).

The part relevant to my inquiry is the following partial statement

> **Proposition 3.1.1: (Lagrange Multiplier Theorem - Necessary Conditions)**
> Let $x^*$ be a local minimum of $f$ subject to $h(x) = 0$, and assume  that the constraint gradients $\nabla h_1(x^*), \dots, \nabla h_m(x^*)$ are linearly independent. Then there exists a unique vector $\lambda^*=(\lambda_1^*, \dots, \lambda_m^*)$ called *Lagrange multiplier vector*, such that
> $$\nabla f(x^*)+\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i^*\nabla h_i(x^*)=0$$
> [...]

Regarding notation, we have the declaration at the start of the section **NECESSARY CONDITIONS FOR EQUALITY CONSTRAINTS**.

> We assume $f:\mathbb{R}^n →\mathbb{R}^n$, $h_i:\mathbb{R}^n→\mathbb{R}$ for $i\in{1,\dots,m}$ are continuously differentiable functions. [...]
> For notational convenience, we introduce the constraint function $h:\mathbb{R}^n→\mathbb{R}^m$, where
> $$h=(h_1,\dots,h_m)$$

For the record, $x^*$ is a local minimum of $f$ if it is the minimizer within a neighborhood of $x^*$. A feasible point is a point that satisfies the constraints given by the problem.

Now, I am going to write down a transcription of the proof presented in the book using the penalty approach.

> **Penalty Approach**
> Here we approximate the original constrainted problem by an unconstrained optimization problem that involves a penalty for violation of the constraints. In particular, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we introduce the cost function
> $$F^k(x)=f(x)+\frac{k}{2}‖h(x)‖^2+\frac{\alpha}{2}‖x-x^*‖^2$$
> where $x^*$ is the local minimum of the constrained problem and $\alpha$ is some positive scalar. [...]
> Since $x^*$ is a local minimum, we can select $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x^*)\leq f(x)$ for all feasible $x$ in the closed sphere
> $$S=\{x : ‖x-x^*‖ \leq \epsilon\}$$
> Let $x^k$ be an optimal solution of the problem of minimizing $F^k$ subject to $x\in S$ [An optimal solution exists because of Weierstrass' theorem [...]].
> We will show that the sequence $\{x^k\}$ converges to $x^*$.
> We have for all $k$
> $$F^k(x)=f(x)+\frac{k}{2}‖h(x)‖^2+\frac{\alpha}{2}‖x-x^*‖^2\leq F^k(x^*)=f(x^*) \tag{1}$$
> and since $f(x^k)$ is bounded over $S$, we obtain
> $$\lim_{k→\infty}‖h(x^k)‖ = 0$$
> otherwise the left hand side of Eq. (1) would become unbounded above as $k→\infty$. Therefore, every limit point $\bar{x}$ of $\{x^k\}$ satisfies $h(\bar{x})=0$. Furthermore, Eq. (1) yields $f(x^k)+\frac{\alpha}{2}‖x^k-x^*‖^2\leq f(x^*)$ for all $k$, so by taking the limit as $k→\infty$, we obtain
> $$f(\bar{x})+\frac{\alpha}{2}‖\bar{x}-x^*‖^2\leq f(x^*)$$
> [...]

My question is very simple regarding to 2 usages of the concept of limit:

- Regarding to this statement

  > We have for all $k$
  > $$F^k(x)=f(x)+\frac{k}{2}‖h(x)‖^2+\frac{\alpha}{2}‖x-x^*‖^2\leq F^k(x^*)=f(x^*) \tag{1}$$
  > and since $f(x^k)$ is bounded over $S$, we obtain
  > $$\lim_{k→\infty}‖h(x^k)‖ = 0$$

  I don't see why can we take the limit to be equal to $0$. As far as I am concerned, we don't know if the sequence $\{x^k\}$ converges at all.
- Regarding this statement

  > Furthermore, Eq. (1) yields $f(x^k)+\frac{\alpha}{2}‖x^k-x^*‖^2\leq f(x^*)$ for all $k$, so by taking the limit as $k→\infty$, we obtain
  > $$f(\bar{x})+\frac{\alpha}{2}‖\bar{x}-x^*‖^2\leq f(x^*)$$

  By the same reason as before, I can't quite justify that $\{x^k\}$ converges.

I have tried modifying the proof by taking a subsequence that converges, as I do see that by being a bounded sequence, $\{x^k\}$ must have a limit point. And by using this subsequence, I see no problem at all when asserting the previous statements.

However, I am probably missing something in the original proof, so I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1.**

> <sup>I don't see why can we take the limit to be equal to $0$. As far as I am concerned, we don't know if the sequence $\{x^k\}$ converges at all.</sup>

There is some misconception here. At this point of the argument, it is *not* that the sequence $\{x^k\}$ converges, but that the sequence $\{\|h(x^k)\|\}$ converges to zero. This is already explained in the excerpt you quote from the book:

> otherwise the left-hand side of Eq. (1) would become unbounded above as $k\to\infty$.

Equation (1) says that:
$$f(x)+\frac{k}{2}‖h(x)‖^2+\frac{\alpha}{2}‖x-x^*‖^2\leq f(x^*) \tag{1}$$
By boundedness (in $S$) of all other quantities except $\frac{k}{2}‖h(x)‖^2$, it follows that there exists some $M>0$ such that for all $k$,
$$
k\|h(x^k)\|\le M\;.
$$
It thus follows that $\lim_k \|h(x^k)\|=0$.

**Question 2.**

The logic regarding your second question is that in order to show that $\lim_{k}x^k=x^*$, the author shows that $\|\bar{x}-x^*\|=0$ for *every* possible [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) $\bar{x}$ of the sequence $\{x^k\}$; this would imply that $x^k$ converges to $x^*$.

Now *if* $\bar{x}$ is a limit point of the sequence $\{x^k\}$, then there exists a subsequence, with common abuse of notation, still denoted as $\{x^k\}$, such that $x^k\to \bar{x}$ as $k\to\infty$. Now by the limit you get in Question 1, and continuity of $h$, you get $h(\bar{x})=0$.

Comment: That's the confirmation I wanted to hear, that it was an abuse of notation.

Answer (score 1):

> We have for all $k$
> $$F^k(x)=f(x)+\frac{k}{2} \|h(x)\|^2+\frac{\alpha}{2} \|x-x^*\|^2 \leq F^k(x^*)=f(x^*) \tag{1}$$
> and since $f(x^k)$ is bounded over $S$, we obtain
> $$\lim_{k→\infty} \|h(x^k)\| = 0$$

As it says, $f(x)$ is bounded, since it is a continuously function over the compact set $S$. Let it be bounded by $\forall x \in S, |f(x)| \le M$. Then since $\alpha>0$, we have:
$$f(x^k)+\frac{k}{2} \|h(x^k)\|^2 \leq f(x^*)$$
So
$$\frac{k}{2} \|h(x^k)\|^2 \leq f(x^*) - f(x^k) \leq 2M$$
And finally
$$\|h(x^k)\|^2 \leq \frac{4M}{k}$$

For the second question, I don't see anywhere that it claims that $\{x^k\}$ converges. Instead, it states that the equation must hold for any limit point $\bar{x}$.

Comment: Thank you, it was useful to confirm some ideas, but I am not completely satisfied.